# How can i convert to right attributes in r dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following problem. Since i collected some data via web scrapping from a greek site about used cars, i save them as a .csv file but, when it comes to import it  in a dataframe, i receive every column as a chr vector. The problem here is when i try to convert them, for instance Price to be as numeric i get a warning message for Nas produced by coercion, i also tried to save it as an xlsx file but again i receive the same kind of problem. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you provide an example of your problem. Roughly, any value that is not viewed as strictly numeric (such as the usage of currency symbols, or `,` for big numbers) are treated as text.

Comment: @Phil i have 11 Columns, Links,Firm,Model,Price,Category,Klm,Fuel_Type,CC,HP,Transmission,Color. For Price, Klm CC and HP i removed everything such € symbol for Price or "χλμ" for Klm and even bhp for HP. Big numbers are seperated by "." and i took that into account when reading the data as data<-read.csv("FINAL.csv",dec = ".")

Comment: The `dec` argument is for decimal points. Again, it would be easier to help if you can provide an example. The `readr` package has functions like `parse_number()` that can make the conversion easier.